# Syntax Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, migration

I have a Node.js app (setup with Typescript) and I'm trying to create Sequelize migrations, but when I run `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`, I get an `import method` error and I can't find the source of the error.

**Folder structure:**

> |dist
>
> | src |
> | --- |
> | config |
> | database.ts |
> | connection |
> | connection.ts |
> | controllers |
> | user.controller.ts |
> | migration |
> | 20231015073945-create-role.ts |
> | models |
> | index.ts |
> | role.ts |
> | routes |
> | role.router.ts |
> | seeders.ts |
> | 20231015075720-role-data.ts |
> |  |
> | server.ts |
> | .sequelizerc |
> | package.json |

````
database.ts//
require('dotenv').config();

//DB Declare;
module.exports = {
  "development": {
    "username": process.env.DEV_DB_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.DEV_DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.DEV_DB_NAME,
    "host": process.env.DEV_DB_HOST,
    "dialect": process.env.DEV_DB_DATABASE_TYPE,
  },
  "test": {
    "username": process.env.TEST_DB_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.TEST_DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.TEST_DB_NAME,
    "host": process.env.TEST_DB_HOST,
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": process.env.PROD_DB_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.PROD_DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.PROD_DB_NAME,
    "host": process.env.PROD_DB_HOST,
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
};



connection.ts//
//Required;
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

//Declare;
let env;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    env = 'test';
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    env = 'production';
} else {
    env = 'development';
}
const config = require('../config/database.ts')[env];

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);


//Conformation;
(async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('Database connection has been established successfully.');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', (err as Error).message);
    }
})();

module.exports = sequelize;



20231015073945-create-role.ts //migration
'use strict';
import { QueryInterface, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface: QueryInterface) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('roles', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      role: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      isActive: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: true
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface: QueryInterface) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('roles');
  }
};


index.ts //models
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import process from 'process';

const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/database.ts')[env];
const db: any = {};

let sequelize: Sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable] as string, config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file: string) => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
      file !== basename &&
      file.slice(-3) === '.ts' &&
      file.indexOf('.test.ts') === -1
    );
  })
  .forEach((file: string) => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;`your text`
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName: string) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

export default db;


role.ts //models
'use strict';
import { Model, DataTypes, Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

interface RoleAttributes {
  id: number;
  role: string;
  isActive: boolean;
}

module.exports = (sequelize: Sequelize) => {
  class Role extends Model<RoleAttributes> {
    static associate() {
      // Define associations here
    }
  }

  Role.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    role: DataTypes.STRING,
    isActive: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'role',
  });

  return Role;
};





server.ts ///////
//Required;
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
require('./src/connection/connection');


//Declare
const port = process.env.PORT







//Server Listen;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});




.sequelizerc
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    'config': path.resolve('src', 'config', 'database.ts'),
    'migrations-path': path.resolve('src', 'migrations'),
    'models-path': path.resolve('src', 'models'),
    'seeders-path': path.resolve('src', 'seeders'),
};




package.json
i am try to add and remove "type: model" method
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.ts",
  "author": "raghul",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.ts",
    "dev": "nodemon server.ts",
    "test": "",
    "build": "tsc",
    "prestart": "yarn run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "init": "^0.1.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.33.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "6.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.19",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.6",
    "tsconfig.json": "^1.0.11",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.ts",
  "author": "raghul",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.ts",
    "dev": "nodemon server.ts",
    "test": "",
    "build": "tsc",
    "prestart": "yarn run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "init": "^0.1.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.33.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "6.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.19",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.6",
    "tsconfig.json": "^1.0.11",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}





tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "ESNext",------------------------> already tryed commonjs also 
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "server.ts",
  ]
}```
````

Comment: `import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';` & `const config = require('../config/database.ts')[env];`  You can't mix commonJS & ES Imports in the same unit in Node.  Although Bun.JS manages it.

Answer (score 0):

typescript uses javascript modules but you are using comonjs type of export you must change your export to javascript module type or in your typescript config file set too support commonjs

javascript module export are like

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config()

const config={
  "development": {
    "username": process.env.DEV_DB_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.DEV_DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.DEV_DB_NAME,
    "host": process.env.DEV_DB_HOST,
    "dialect": process.env.DEV_DB_DATABASE_TYPE,
  },
  "test": {
    "username": process.env.TEST_DB_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.TEST_DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.TEST_DB_NAME,
    "host": process.env.TEST_DB_HOST,
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": process.env.PROD_DB_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.PROD_DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.PROD_DB_NAME,
    "host": process.env.PROD_DB_HOST,
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
};

export default config;
```

or you can do like this :

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config()

export const config={
  "development": {
    "username": process.env.DEV_DB_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.DEV_DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.DEV_DB_NAME,
    "host": process.env.DEV_DB_HOST,
    "dialect": process.env.DEV_DB_DATABASE_TYPE,
  },
  "test": {
    "username": process.env.TEST_DB_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.TEST_DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.TEST_DB_NAME,
    "host": process.env.TEST_DB_HOST,
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": process.env.PROD_DB_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.PROD_DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.PROD_DB_NAME,
    "host": process.env.PROD_DB_HOST,
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
};
```